# Give a relation $X\subseteq A\times A$, so that $R\subseteq X$ and $X$ is symmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

$R=\{(2,5),(3,4)\}$

$A=\{2,3,4,5\}$

my answer:
$X=\{(2,5)(5,2)\}$

$X$ is a proper subset because it contains not all elements of $A\times A$ and not all elements of $R$. And $X$ is symmetric because it contains the pairs $(2,5)$ and $(5,2)$

Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since $R$ should be a subset of $X$. Instead, from your answer we have that $(3,4) \in R$ but $(3,4) \notin X$. So to fix this, we should put $(3,4)$ in $X$. But then since $X$ must be symmetric, what else must also go in $X$?

Note that $R$ is a proper subset of $X$ iff every element of $R$ is also in $X$ but $X$ contains an element that is not in $R$. Since $(5,2) \in X$ but $(5,2) \notin R$, we don't need to worry about $X$ being improper.

Comment: (4,3) should also be in X, to make X symmetric
{(2,5),(5,2),(3,4),(4,3)} is the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.